# Error: auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

```
const firebase = require("firebase-admin");
const auth=firebase.auth();
// create user in firebase data
    var actionCodeSettings = {
      // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
      // URL must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.
      url: 'https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234',
      // This must be true.
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      dynamicLinkDomain: 'example.page.link'
    };
    // [END auth_email_link_actioncode_settings]
app.get("/firebase/api/createUser",function(req,resp){
    auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail("sagar@gmail.com",actionCodeSettings)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    var user = userCredential.user;
    console.log("user created :"+user);
    resp.send("--"+userCredential);
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
});
```

It gives me an error. the setting I already enable in firebase.
What is issue here?
This function was written in the firebase cloud function.

Answer (score 3):

Sending emails and SMS messages to a user with Firebase Authentication is only possible with the client-side SDKs.

You're using the **Admin SDK**, which does not have this functionality, as it would be too prone to abuse.

So you will have to implement this functionality in the client-side application code, using the regular client-side/Web SDK for Firebase Authentication.

Comment: So this function we cannot write on firebase cloud functions ???

Comment: That is correct. The request to send the `sendSignInLinkToEmail` must come from a device where the user signed in.