# Is there any REST api to create user in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Is there any REST API to create a user in Firebase?
i want same like this function sendSignInLinkToEmail.  we don't want to provide sign-up, from diff application we call API to create users & provide them names & passwords.

this is not working: [Error: auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439185/error-auth-sendsigninlinktoemail-is-not-a-function/67439495#67439495)

Comment: You could use both client and admin sdk in your project

Comment: The REST API for Firebase Authentication is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth I don't immediately see a method to send an email sign-in link though.